# Labeling Syntax in R Boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, dplyr

Trying to establish "range" labels on a boxplot:

```
x <- getURL('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dothemathonthatone/maps/master/maindf_2_Anon.csv')

maindf <- read.csv(text = x, row.names=NULL, head =TRUE, dec = ',')

maindf$fee_per_inc <- as.numeric(as.character(maindf$fee_per_inc))

summary(maindf$year_hh_inc)  



Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   7501   35000   50001   56446   75001  500014 

maindf <- maindf %>% 
 mutate(category = cut(year_hh_inc, 
                       breaks = (quantile(year_hh_inc, c(0, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 1), na.rm = TRUE)), 
                       labels = c("€ 7,501 - € 35,000", "35,001 - 50,001", "50,002 - 75,001", "75,002 - 500,001"), 
                       include.lowest = TRUE), 
        vals = 1) 

maindf <- maindf[maindf$fee_per_inc > 0 & maindf$fee_per_inc < 0.0001, ]

box  <- boxplot(maindf$fee_per_inc ~ maindf$category, col = 3:5)
```

[image: output]

I would like to label each box with the ranges from the `summary` call. For some reason it is only picking up two boxes. Does someone have an idea on that?

And I sure wish there was something that could be done about those colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels are already "there", but R's native plot method will drop axis labels if they are going to clash, so you just need to shrink the axis text:

```r
boxplot(maindf$fee_per_inc ~ maindf$category, col = 3:5, cex.axis = 0.9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the labels are not shown in full is simple: they are too long. The solution is simple too: just adjust three arguments to `boxplot`:

First, increase/decrease the margins around the boxplot so you have more space for spacious labels by adjusting the values in `mar`; for example, you make the space *under* the boxplot large enough for the lables to fit under:

```
 par(mfrow = c(1,1), mar = c(8,4,1,4))
```

Then/Or adjust the character size of the axis labels by decreasing `cex.axis`(it defaults to 1)

And finally you can set `las = 2`to flip the labels' direction.
You also mention colors as problematic: you can easily change them in any way you want by defining the colors of your choice in the argument `col`:

```
boxplot(women$height, women$weight, 
        names = c("A long variable name", "B another long name"),
        cex.axis = 0.8,
        las = 2,
        col = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]